# How to pull metrics in prometheus using client_golang

Tags: json, http, go, prometheus

I am trying to write a JSON exporter in GoLang using   [**client_golang**](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/tree/master/examples/simple.)

I could not find any useful example for this. I have a service ABC that produces JSON output over HTTP. I want to use the client-golang to export this metric to prometheus.

Comment: Do you want pulling metrics by prometheus? Or do you want push metrics to prometheus pushgateway? If you want pulling metrics you should register metrics via http like this: https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/examples/random/main.go

Comment: I have a service which produces JSON output over HTTP.I need a GoLang example which reads JSON from this HTTP and pass it to prometheus.

Comment: https://www.robustperception.io/writing-json-exporters-in-python/
something like this in GoLang.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the godoc for the Go client, it is very detailed and contains plenty of examples. The one for the Collector interface is probably the most relevant here:

https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#example-Collector

Essentially, you would implement the Collector interface, which contains two methods: `describe` and `collect`.

`describe` simply sends descriptions for the possible Metrics of your Collector over the given channel. This includes their name, possible label values and help string.

`collect` creates actual metrics that match the descriptions from `describe` and populates them with data. So in your case, it would GET the JSON from your service, unmarshal it, and write values to the relevant metrics.

In your `main` function, you then have to register your collector, and start the HTTP server, like this:

```
prometheus.MustRegister(NewCustomCollector())
http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to write an exporter for your own service using golang? The exporters listed on [prometheus exporter page](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exporters/) are all good examples, many of which are written in golang, you could pick a simple one like [redis exporter](https://github.com/oliver006/redis_exporter) to see how it's implemented.

Basically what you need to do is:

1. Define your own `Exporter` type
2. Implement interface [prometheus.Collector](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector), you can poll the json data from your service and build metrics based on it
3. Register your own `Exporter` to prometheus by [prometheus.MustRegister](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#MustRegister)
4. Start a HTTP server and expose metrics endpoint for prometheus to poll metrics